# When to use "respectively"?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I have been wondering what it means when people use "respectively" in, before, and after sentences. For example:

> We are looking for a babysitter to pick up and supervise our kids ages
>   6 and 3, respectively, on Monday and Friday.

I don't know if this person used it correctly, but if they did what does it mean? If they didn't use it properly what would be the proper usage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be a correct usage. You have to have identified the specific referents *individually* before you can provide a "parallel list" of attribute values applicable to *each, in that order.* As for example, *"...supervise our **son** and **daughter**, aged **6** and **3** respectively"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Respectively](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/respectively) means 'in the order described'. I think this is a lovely example where one might make a number of interpretations concerning the author's intentions:

"We are looking for a babysitter to pick up and supervise our kids ages 6 and 3, respectively" could mean they want someone to pick up their 6-year old and supervise their 3-year old.

"...our kids ages 6 and 3, respectively, on Monday and Friday" could mean they want their 6-year old picked up and supervised on Monday and their 3-year old picked up and supervised on Friday.

I believe some people also use respectively simply to list individual items; "We have two kids, aged 6 and 3 respectively".

I'm not expert enough to say that this is incorrect use of the word, but it is certainly very ambiguous.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be a correct usage. "You have to have identified the **specific referents** (/actions) individually **before** you can provide a "parallel list" of attribute values applicable to each, in that order." 'Kids' doesn't identify disjoint referents. You need "pick up our 6-year-old and supervise our 3-year-old" here (and now "on Mondays and Fridays respectively" works). (+1 to FF for a fine answer)

Answer (score 6):

A normal use might be:

'We have a son and daughter, aged 7 and 4 respectively', meaning that the son is 7 and the daughter is 4.

It is quite pointless to use 'respectively' without earlier reference. It would be like saying 'We have a cat and a dog respectively'. The 'respectively' in that example would be as useless as the human appendix!

Comment: More useless perhaps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermiform_appendix#Maintaining_gut_flora

Comment: So tired of this constant berating of the human appendix. I go to english.stackexchange.com to avoid the topic altogether, not to become inundated with uninformed opinions on the matter.

Comment: So why do people use that word then? it seems kinada pointless, because the vast majority of the time, there isn't a special order or anything. is it a culture thing?

Comment: @MarcusJ Well, can you see any point in adding *respectively* to "We have a cat and a dog"? Unless it was *Jane and I have a cat and a dog respectively*, which would mean that Jane has a cat and I have a dog.

Comment: I can see the point, I guess I just assume people say things in the order they mean them.

Comment: turns out the appendix does a lot: http://www.sciencefocus.com/news/what-does-appendix-do-lot-more-we-thought%E2%80%A6