# How to punctuate and make concise a sentence that contains a list and then describes each item in the list?

Tags: punctuation, lists, semicolons, colons, concision

How to punctuate and make concise a sentence that contains a list and then describes each item in the list?

One possible structure of the sentence I would like to punctuate is:

> I do not have any formal experience in research aside from papers in XXX, YYY, and ZZZ [?][?] in XXX I explored xxx [?] in YYY I researched yyy [?] and in ZZZ I wrote about zzz.

I was thinking about putting a colon for the first blank and semicolons for the rest, but I think this repeats words unnecessarily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use "respectively"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138695/when-to-use-respectively)

Comment: A sentence with all that in can't be concise.

Comment: Make it several sentences. Why do people think they only get one sentence and they have to make it as complicated as possible?